# Trying to change a button's border color in Xamarin code behind on a Clicked event

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

This just doesn't seem to be working, but of course, I feel like it really should be. Can't figure out what's wrong here. I have a button with a border that's set to transparent in the xaml. I want the border color to change to white when the button is pressed. Very simple. But yeah, any help would be appreciated. Here's my event:

```
private void FactionChosen(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if ((sender as Button).BorderColor == Color.Transparent)
        {
            (sender as Button).BorderColor = Color.White;
        }
        else if ((sender as Button).BorderColor == Color.White)
        {
            (sender as Button).BorderColor = Color.Transparent;
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried setting a value to `BorderWidth` 3 for example ? could you share the xaml part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned previously in [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65543515/trying-to-change-a-buttons-border-color-in-xamarin-code-behind-on-a-clicked-eve/65546606#comment115885215_65543515), two possible reasons could be the cause:

1. You are not setting a value to `BorderWidth`, [by default it has 0 as value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.button.borderwidth?view=xamarin-forms)

`<Button Text="OK" BorderWidth="3" BorderColor="Transparent" Clicked="FactionChosen"/>`

2. Your `Button` is in a white background (the `BackgroundColor` of it Parent is white), it is straightforward that the `BackgroundColor` of the Parent control and the `BorderColor` of your Button must be different.

Answer (score 0):

You should set a BorderWidth value.

```
<Button Text="Click Me" Clicked="FactionChosen" BorderColor="Transparent" BorderWidth="5" />
```

[image]